# Meaning of XOR in programming? What does it change an integer value to?

Tags: algorithm, optimization

What does a XOR operator change a integer to ? Can we get some optimised thing out of it ?

```
int arr[7]={1,5,7,9,5,2,5};
int xora[7];
xora[0]=0;
for(i=1; i<7; i++)
     xora[i] = xora[i-1]^arr[i];
```

After this what is the significance of `xor[i]` now?
Can this be some kind of optimisation ?
xora comes out to be 
 `5       2       11      14      12      9`
What does this numbers specify ?
[Linked to a programming problem's solution Here](https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/stone-game-a39dbbe7/)

Comment: `some optimised thing` - relative to what? The `xor` operator is used frequently in encryption, among any number of other applications. - Your question is too vague.

Comment: The linked game is Nim, you can read about its relation to XOR [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim#Mathematical_theory)

Answer (score 0):

To understand XOR we need to go to the bit level. For two bits, x and y,

x^y = xy' + x'y where x' is complementary of x.

x^y = 1 if x is not equal to y

x^y = 0 if x is equal to y.

In case of integer, it performs XOR of individual bits of the integer.

Here,

```
xora[1] = xora[0]^arr[1] = 0^5 = (0000)^(0101) = (0101) = 5 

// considering 4 bits only for integer and (.) represent bit representation  

xora[2] = xora[1]^arr[2] = 5^7 = (0101)^(0111) = (0010) = 2 
xora[3] = xora[2]^arr[3] = 2^9 = (0010)^(1001) = (1011) = 11 

// and so on.
```